# Carrirage return not recognized in VBScript variable (Passed from SQL Server)

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript file that accepts a variety of parameters, one of which is a text string from a varchar(max) field in SQL Server, which is used in the script as the .HTMLBody of an e-mail message.

However, when the e-mail message is created and displayed, all of the text is jumbled together, making it somewhat difficult to read since it ignores all line breaks.

The actual script is called from a Java application like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arguments)
```

Where arguments is a list of arguments pass into the VBScript file, which is also part of the arguments string like this:

```
wscript filepath\sendEmail + arguments
```

Each argument is held in quotes to segment each unique parameter in the VBScript file, which is structured like this:

```
Set objArgs = WScript.Arguments
Arg1 = objArgs(0)
...
Set MyApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
...
.HTMLBody = Arg8
```

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

-Brian

Answer (score 0):

According to [this doc for HTMLBody Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa171418%28v=office.11%29.aspx), `.HTMLBody` deals with HTML:

```
.HTMLBody = "<HTML><BODY>Enter the message text here. </BODY></HTML>"
```

As whitespace has reduced significance in HTML, you should replace (whatever) line-endings of your input text with `<br>` (or `<br />`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  However, I need a way to determine where the line breaks are in the string from SQL Server, so that I can replace them with <br> tags in the HTMLBody section of the e-mail.

Comment: @user2044281 Can't you simply run `Replace(str, vbCr, "<br/>")`?